# How to specify more than one grokCustomPatterns in Athena?

Tags: logstash-grok, amazon-athena

I'm trying to use Grok expressions in Athena, mostly as a tool to debug Grok expressions in AWS Glue Classifiers.

This works:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE example_grok (
  myColumn string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
 'com.amazonaws.glue.serde.GrokSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'input.format'='(%{WORD:header},%{WORD:file_type},%{GREEDYDATA:head_rest})|(%{DETAILS:det},%{WORD:icp_number},%{GREEDYDATA:det_rest})',
'input.grokCustomPatterns' = 'DETAILS DET'
)
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
 OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
 's3://my-secret-bucket/path/';
```

I would like to specify several custom patterns, but [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/grok.html) doesn't have an example, and none of the delimiters that I have tried, either inside or outside of the string, have worked.

For example, these do *NOT* work

New line delimited (with no leading spaces, those are just for this post):

```
 'input.grokCustomPatterns' = 
 'POSTFIX_QUEUEID [0-9A-F]{7,12}
HEADER HDR'
```

As a "json" array:

```
'input.grokCustomPatterns' = ['POSTFIX_QUEUEID [0-9A-F]{7,12}','HEADER HDR']
```

With multiple entries:

```
'input.grokCustomPatterns'='HEADER (HDR)',
'input.grokCustomPatterns'='POSTFIX_QUEUEID [0-9A-F]{7,12}',
```

Any assistance is appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS responded to the documentation improvement that I requested.  A literal `\n` separates patterns.

> To include multiple pattern entries into the input.grokCustomPatterns
>   expression, use the newline escape character (\n) to separate them, as
>   follows: 'input.grokCustomPatterns'='INSIDE_QS
>   ([^\"]*)\nINSIDE_BRACKETS ([^\]]*)').

[Grok Serde](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/grok.html)